# not able to retrieve key and values from form.errors

Tags: python, django-templates, django-views

I want to retrieve errors in text format and pass key, error dictionary to form but it shows that form.errors is not  iterable

```
def signup(request):
forms={}
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if form.errors:
            for key,value in form.errors.items:
                forms[key]=BeautifulSoup(value,'html.parser').get_text() 
else:
    form = SignUpForm()
return render(request, 'signup.html',{'forms':forms})
```

and in template is :

```
<script>
{% for key,value in forms.items %} 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name={{key}}]').parent().addClass("alert-validate");
        $('input[name={{key}}]').parent().attr("data-validate", "{{value}}");
    });
    {% endfor %}
<script>
```

gives error at

```
for key,value in form.errors.items:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `form.errors.items()` and not `form.errors.items`

```
...
        if form.errors:
            for key,value in form.errors.items():
                forms[key]=BeautifulSoup(value,'html.parser').get_text()
...
```